# Why I am seeing the name attribute of file tag in the html for when I call getName() in Servlet?

Tags: java, servlets

So this is in my web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>UploadFileServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.tugay.julyseventeen.UploadFileServlet</servlet-class>
    <multipart-config>
        <max-file-size>20000</max-file-size>
        <file-size-threshold>20000</file-size-threshold>
    </multipart-config>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>UploadFileServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/uploadFile</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And the form I have:

```
<form action="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/uploadFile" method="post"
      enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="name">Your name here:
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name"/>
    </label>
    <input type="file" name="xxx" id="file"/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

And in the Servlet I have:

```
public class UploadFileServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        String name = httpServletRequest.getParameter("name");
        Part file = httpServletRequest.getPart("xxx");

        InputStream inputStream = file.getInputStream();
        int read;
        final byte[] bytes = new byte[1024000];

        System.out.println(file.getName());

    }
}
```

So here file.getName() will return me "xxx" which I do not like. I want to get the name of the file being uploaded. How can I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Servlet API 3.1, the `Part` interface provides the [`getSubmittedFileName()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/Part.html#getSubmittedFileName%28%29) method which does what you need.

> Gets the file name specified by the client

Answer (score 0):

Use [Commons Fileupload library](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/) provided by Apache that makes it easy to add robust, high-performance, file upload capability to your servlets and web applications.

Sample code:

```
 List<FileItem> multiparts = new ServletFileUpload(
                            new DiskFileItemFactory()).parseRequest(request);

 for(FileItem item : multiparts){
    if(!item.isFormField()){
        String name = new File(item.getName()).getName();

    }
 }
```

Find complete code [here](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/08/file-upload-example-in-servlet-and-jsp.html) and [here](http://srikanthtechnologies.com/articles/j2ee/fileupload.html)

Answer (score 0):

I did something very similar recently using a Multipart file, and using ajax to post to my controller.

Form:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="inputForm">
    <input id="file" type="file" name="file" />
</form>

<input onclick="Javascript: upload()" type="submit" value="Upload" />
```

JS:

```
function upload() {
    var data = new FormData($('#inputForm')[0]);
    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : 'upload',
        data : data,
        cashe : false,
        contentType : false,
        processData : false,
        success : function(response) {
           alert(response);
        },
        error : function() {
           alert("Didn't work");
        }
    });
}
```

Controller:

```
@ResponseBody
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String upload(@RequestBody MultipartFile file) {
    System.out.println("Uploaded - " + file.getOriginalFilename());
}
```

This should give you the file name you're looking for.

I don't know if you're using SpringMVC or not, but if you are, this is what I did.  You're going to want to import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile for the MultipartFile.